# IBAction won't work

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

The following IBAction will run when I don't have `bookCoverUp.alpha = 0;` in the code, but as soon as I add that code, and try running the program, the IBAction stops working completely.

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    bookCoverUp.alpha = 0;
    //this sends you to the desired viewcontroller
    SimpleTableView *newWindow = [self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newWindow animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error or is the method never called? What is the problem?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to see if it still gets run.

Comment: If  bookCoverUp is the respective button then @BlackRider has mentioned the expected behaviour.

Comment: Using the help you guys gave me I figured out a way around this. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: Instead I just made it so the visibility relied on a boolean, then changed the boolean value for a new instance of the class when the action was necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for invisible views.

From [the Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html):

> To hide a view visually, you can either set its hidden property to YES
>   or change its alpha property to 0.0. A hidden view does not receive
>   touch events from the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a transparent button, change your button type to "Custom" (or in code, UIButtonTypeCustom) and don't give it a background colour or background image - it is transparent by default.